# ClassList.add() for multiple divs with same className - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

I have a number of divs with the same `className` (**.example**). I'm attempting to add classes to the classList of each of them using vanilla JavaScript, and successfully do so, but only for the first div of which possesses the targeted `className`, as shown using the following code:

```
<html>
 <body> 
  <div class="example">content</div>
  <div class="example">content</div>
  <div class="example">content</div>
 </body>
</html>


var example = document.querySelector('.example');

if (className = ('.example')){
  example.classList.add('margin');
}
```

this does the following:

```
<html>
 <body> 
  <div class="example margin">content</div>
  <div class="example">content</div>
  <div class="example">content</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, I wish to do this:

```
<html>
 <body> 
  <div class="example margin">content</div>
  <div class="example margin">content</div>
  <div class="example margin">content</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information for you, thank you in advance!

Comment: Use querySelectorAll and iterate the list of elements returned for the same selector

Comment: Apart from your question, which has been properly answered, I don't think the condition for your `if` statement does what you think it does.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I have also explained about the unnecessary `if` statement. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **loop** through the elements using `querySelectorAll()` and not `querySelector()` to add classes and there's no `if` you need to use:

```js
// Select all the elements with example class.
var examples = document.querySelectorAll('.example');

// Loop through the elements.
for (var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
  // Add the class margin to the individual elements.
  examples[i].classList.add('margin');
}
```

```html
<div class="example">content</div>
<div class="example">content</div>
<div class="example">content</div>
```

The code above is well commented. Let me know if you have any questions.